# How do I create a select box with a for loop in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to React and Redux and I want to create a React/Redux implementation of [Chess Queens](http://chess-queens.sourceforge.net/). I want to create constants, such as `MAX_BOARD_SIZE = 50`, and create a select box with all the numbers from 1 to `MAX_BOARD_SIZE`. When changing the board size the board size will change automatically. But I can't create the for loop inside my `SelectBoardSize` render function. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

class SelectBoardSize extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <select className="select-board-size">
                for (let i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
                   <option value="{i}">{i}</option>
                }
            </select>
        );
    }
}

export default SelectBoardSize;
```

And I also don't know where to define the constants and how to use this value in this class? The constants should be defined in another file, for example `constants.jsx` or somewhere outside this class file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define your constants in `./constants.js` file.

`export const MAX_BOARD_SIZE = 24;`

Then import them like:

`import { MAX_BOARD_SIZE } from './constants`;

Also it's impossible to use `for` in jsx, so you can use `map` instead.

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { MAX_BOARD_SIZE } from './constants'

class SelectBoardSize extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <select className="select-board-size">
                { _.range(1, MAX_BOARD_SIZE + 1).map(value => <option key={value} value={value}>{value}</option>) }
            </select>
        );
    }
}

export default SelectBoardSize;
```

Comment: nice one, like it

Comment: I prefer to import the constants without using state. If you change it to importing MAX_BOARD_SIZE I can accept this answer.

Comment: Just one problem - this outputs board sizes from 0 to MAX_BOARD_SIZE - 1. I need from 1 to MAX_BOARD_SIZE. How do I change the array? I wrote ```{ Array.from(new Array(MAX_BOARD_SIZE),(value, index) => index + 1).map(value => <option key={value} value={value}>{value}</option>) }```, is there a way to make this line shorter?

Comment: Right now I can only think of using lodash library https://lodash.com/docs/#range `range` method :)

Answer (score 11):

You can not use any JS code you want (like for loops) inside jsx code. Try this

P.S Regarding constants: it's up to you where to keep your constants. I prefer to save them in separate file. But if it component-dependent (rather than app-dependent) constant you could define it inside component file

```js
import React from 'react';

class SelectBoardSize extends React.Component {
    buildOptions() {
        var arr = [];

        for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            arr.push(<option key={i} value="{i}">{i}</option>)
        }

        return arr; 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <select className="select-board-size">
                {this.buildOptions()}
            </select>
        );
    }
}

export default SelectBoardSize;
```

Comment: How do I define constants in a separate file and use them in this class?

Comment: Use export syntax. Create constants.js file and `export const MAX_BOARD_SIZE = 50`. Inside component file use `import { MAX_BOARD_SIZE } from './constants'`